# Where does the mail utility store read mail?

Tags: macos, email

I have a few cron jobs that mail their output to my username. I check this mail in the terminal by typing `mail`. When I quit the mail program with 'q' it says "Saved X messages in mbox" (where X is the number of messages I just read).

How can I read those messages again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted a full featured editor / mail client from the command line:

```
brew install mutt
```

If you just want to see the mail you can use the `from` command to see headers or look at the files in `/var/mail/${USER}`. Depending on how you disposed of messages, they also might be in your `~/mbox` file

Some good reading at:

- [OS X: Read mbox formatted files in /var/mail (local mail) graphically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13648/os-x-read-mbox-formatted-files-in-var-mail-local-mail-graphically)
- [Where is my mbox located at?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230040/where-is-my-mbox-located-at)
- https://superuser.com/questions/306163/what-is-the-you-have-new-mail-message-in-linux-unix

Comment: `~/mbox` is just what I was looking for. `/var/mail/${USER}` only shows my unread mail.